# Formatting numbers for a barcode as text for readability in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, number-formatting

Is there a way to format text is a specific way similar to how one would format a number? I'm attempting to display a barcode's numbers within a cell in a more readable format. I'm using UPCs, and because a UPC has a leading zero, I can't use number formatting if I want to keep the leading zero stored, I need to store the barcode as text. Is there any way I can store the barcode within the cell like this:

[image: Cell data (text)]

but have my cell display like this:

[image: Cell display (text)]

I've tried custom number formatting of `0 00000 00000 0;@`, but this will truncate the leading zero in the data (seen below), and simply display a leading zero. This breaks some conditional formatting on the cell where it checks the length of the data within the cell and if the length is not equal to 12 (the length of a UPC), the cell will have a red fill.

Data:

[image: Data (number)]

Display:

[image: Display (number)]

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a second column showing the barcode in the format you want using something like (if your barcode of 12 digits in in cell A1):

```
=Left(A1,1)&" "&mid(A1,2,5)&" "&mid(A1,6,5)&" "&right(A1)
```

Not exactly what you're looking for but maybe a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You may try changing the conditional formatting rule(s). Take for instance the rule is looking at `A2`'s length, make this portion as `TEXT(A2, "0 00000 00000 0;@")` and change the length criteria from 12 to 15.

But still, if the barcode value is 7 digits, the formatting will convert this to 15 characters (filling 5 leading zeros) in any case and the conditional formatting will not be working properly & will show that the cell's length is OK every time.

In this case, the best solution might be is to convert the barcode column to text (so in this case the leading zeros will remain), and create a helper column with below formula; your conditional formatting will still be looking at the old text column but you will be using this new column, maybe hide that old column:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(A2)
```